# String equality not evaluating to true

Tags: java, split

I use split function

```
string = data.con_loop[i].split("\\.");
```

The string input is "0.9.L". But,

```
string[2]=="L"
```

doesn't evaluate to `true`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `equals("L")` instead of `==`.

```
if(string[2].equals("L"))...
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use the `compareTo(string)` function :

`if(string[2].compareTo("L")){ // then }`

`.compareTo()` function returns you `0` if the string is equal to the content you specified.

You should read the official doc :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Edit : If `compareTo()` function doesn't work, try `compareToIgnoreCase()`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string[2]=="L")
```

change that to

```
if(string[2].equals("L"))
```

In your case **==** will check whether the references of those two objects are same or not. So if you want to check their contents then you have to use **equals()** method.

NOTE: **==** works on the concept of **string interning**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need double slashes, then use equals to check

```
string = data.con_loop[i].split("\.");
if(string[2].equals("L")) {
    //.....
}
```